# Can't get S3 Uploads to work in Xcode 10.2/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am in the process of building an iOS App, and I've been stuck on S3 uploads for a few days. I have been following the documentation provided here:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage.

When I hit this function it appears as if everything worked in Xcode, and it returns no errors. However, when I go look in my S3 bucket I see that the image was never uploaded. Here is my upload function (I put the credential info in here as well):

I think my source of confusion is coming from getting credentials from Cognito. I feel like I need Cognito credentials to access the AWS Transfer Utility, and the code below seems like it should be doing that?

```
@IBAction func uploadData() {

    let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast2, identityPoolId: "us-east-2:XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX", identityProviderManager:pool)
    let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast2, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "XXXX", clientSecret: "XXXX", poolId: "us-east-XXXX")

    let tu = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()

    AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: serviceConfiguration!, transferUtilityConfiguration: tu, forKey: "UserPool")

    let transferUtility:(AWSS3TransferUtility?) = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "UserPool")
    AWSServiceManager.default()?.defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration


    let data = self.imageView?.image?.pngData() // Data to be uploaded

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
        })
    }

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.
            // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
        })
    }

    transferUtility!.uploadData(data as! Data,
                               bucket: "mybucket-env",
                               key: "YourFileName",
                               contentType: "image/png",
                               expression: expression,
                               completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                (task) -> AnyObject? in
                                if let error = task.error {
                                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }

                                if let _ = task.result {
                                    // Do something with uploadTask.
                                }
                                return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you generated your client credentials (key/ secret) at Cognito already?

Comment: Here're two articles that might help:
[generating credentials](https://robkerr.com/tutorial-using-amazon-aws-s3-storage-with-your-ios-swift-app/)
and, [the client code](https://github.com/maximbilan/Swift-Amazon-S3-Uploading-Tutorial) It looks like your code is correct.

Comment: @shunzhe M - I do have the client credentials created at this point. I just checked out those two links and it looks like those are referencing the TransferManager instead of TransferUtility, which XCode is saying is depracated :(

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has been updated: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage

You can achieve the same functionality using AWS Amplify where you can use

1. Amplify CLI to provision S3 and cognito resources
2. Add configuration files to your app, `awsconfiguration.json` and `amplifyconfiguration.json`.
3. Install the dependencies

```
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin'
pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.12.0'
```

3. Initialize AWSMobileClient and Amplify
4. Amplify.Storage.uploadData()